# 3D resources for VB.NET programmers

Tags: vb.net, 3d

I want to learn 3D programming within the Microsoft Windows .NET environment. My best .NET language is VB.NET.

My aim is to be able to create **3D images** only. I do not want to create 3D videos or 3D games.

Any suggestion of books or online resources that are suitable for VB.NET users like me?

**UPDATE:**

I know nothing about 3D programming and only have limited experiences in 2D graphics programming under .NET

I can work in all versions of VB.NET and Visual Studio (2003-2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with last visual studio and you don't need an advanced 
rendering, then you can skip use of XNA (3D engine in directx for windows 
and XBOX), you can use WPF and XAML Viewport3D object and 3D objects.

Here some examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437.aspx

http://kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm

http://www.wpftutorial.net/IntroductionTo3D.html

Comment: Not readed, but after a search i find this: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Three-Dimensional-Presentation-Foundation/dp/0735623945

Comment: I too, now searching books at amazon :)

Comment: For making some base 3d, it can be perfect. But if you planning to do more extra feats, then maybe you need to use XNA. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to write your own 3D Rendering Engine that can generate 3D Images than you might want to start by reading articles about raytracing implemenation on devmaster.net.

Also on amazon you can buy a book called Physically Based Rendering, Second Edition: From Theory To Implementation. This book is a bible of writing pbrt systems, I highly recommend it for you

Comment: This is a bit like telling someone who wants to learn programming to start by writing a compiler.